# Error in Ordinary Differential Equation representation

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

**UPDATE**
I am trying to find the Lyapunov Exponents given in link [LE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4628-calculation-lyapunov-exponents-for-ode). I am trying to figure it out and understand it by taking the following eqs for my case. These are a set of ordinary differential equations (these are just for testing how to work with cos and sin as ODE)

```
f(1)=ALPHA*(y-x);
f(2)=x*(R-z)-y;
f(3) = 10*cos(x);
```

and `x=X(1); y=X(2); cos(y)=X(3);`

f1 means `dx/dt`;f2 `dy/dt` and f3 in this case would be `-10sinx`. However,when expressing as x=X(1);y=X(2);i am unsure how to express for cos.This is just a trial example i was doing so as to know how to work with equations where we have a cos,sin etc terms as a function of another variable.

When using ode45 to solve these Eqs

```
[T,Res]=sol(3,@test_eq,@ode45,0,0.01,20,[7 2 100 ],10);
```

it throws the following error

??? Attempted to access (2); index must be a positive integer or logical.

```
Error in ==> Eq at 19
x=X(1); y=X(2); cos(x)=X(3);
```

1. Is my representation `x=X(1); y=X(2); cos(y)=X(3);` alright?
2. How to resolve the error?
   Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No your representation is completely wrong.
You can't possibly set values in this way!
For a start, you are trying to assign a value `X(3)` to a *function*.

first I am not sure you understand the difference between

```
x=4
```

and

```
4=x
```

which are completely different meanings. If you understand this, you'll see that you can't possibly assign using `cos(x)=X(3)`.

Second: what is the function `sol()` you are calling? have you defined it?

Third, to solve or evaluate ODEs you should be using `deval` or `solve` functions in matlab. Their help files should give you examples.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Well,I am trying to do something like this given in the link http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4628-calculation-lyapunov-exponents-for-ode SO in the link,the authors use ode_45 and set values like that.The problem in my case is with cosine functions since it is dependent on x variable and hence how to differentiate and assign values to it?Please help.

Comment: The page you linked to seems to be for finding lyapunov exponents. Is that what you are trying to do? If not, what are you trying to do? Does `f` in your statement above mean derivative of `X` ie. dX/dt? if so, please post your full function definition (starting with the word `function`) and the full definition of `sol`. Without this, we can't help!

Comment: Im trying to find the lyapunov exponents and f1 does mean dx/dt;f2 dy/dt and f3 in this case would be -10sinx.However,when expressing as x=X(1);y=X(2);i am unsure how to express for cos.This is just a trial example i was doing so as to know how to work with equations where we have a cos,sin etc terms as a function of another variable.